# replace position of DOM element and preserve its events

Tags: jquery, events, replacewith

I am writing a jquery plugin that gets a table and allow to change the columns order.
The code for putting the column that in position oldIndex in position newIndex is:

```
table.find('> thead > tr, > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var children = row.children();
    var source = $(children[oldIndex ]);
    var destination = $(children[newIndex ]);

    if (oldIndex != newIndex ) {
        destination
            .replaceWith(source)
            .appendTo(row);
    }
});
```

The problem is that each td has events that came outside this code. When using `replaceWith`, it removes those events.

Any idea hoe can I replace position of DOM element and preserve its events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the bound functions are attached to the to-be-moved element.

Instead of using [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), I suggest to use logic to swap the columns. [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is used to select the index of a specific column, [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) are used to swap the columns:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SfwXg/

```
// Indexes are zero-based
var oldIndex = 1;  // = Second column
var newIndex = 2;  // = Third column
var table = $('table');

if (oldIndex != newIndex) {
    if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
        // Let newIndex always be higher than oldIndex
        var tmp = oldIndex;
        oldIndex = newIndex;
        newIndex = oldIndex;
    }
    table.find('> thead > tr, > tbody > tr').each(function() {
//or:table.children('thead,tbody').children().each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var children = row.children();
        
        var right = children.eq(newIndex);
        var left = children.eq(oldIndex);
        
        children.eq(newIndex).after(left);
        if (newIndex != oldIndex+1) {
           // If they're next to each other, don't swap the columns
           children.eq(oldIndex+1).before(right);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: oldIndex and newIndex are defind before the call to 'each'.

Comment: This doesn't work.. What is the difference between children.eq(index) and $(children[index]) ?

Comment: @Naor `$(children[index])` retrieves a DOM element from the jQuery collection, and wraps it in a new jQuery object. `children.eq(index)` returns the *index*-th jQuery object from the jQuery collection. Do you have any demo (http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Naor Instead of using `replaceWith`, you'd better just swap the elements, using `after` and `before`. See my edit and demo. This code cannot cause events to disappear. If it did, your problem is caused by something else, not related to this code.

Comment: @Naor [`$a.insertBefore($b)`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) is equal to [`$b.before($a)`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).

Comment: replaceWith *does* remove event handlers from the element being removed (replaced). You can see from https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js that it uses .remove internally, and http://api.jquery.com/remove/ documents that events are removed.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen Thanks, I've revised the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (oldIndex != newIndex ) {
    var tmp = $('<td>').insertBefore(destination); // create tmp td before destination
    source.after(destination); // move destination after source
    tmp.after(source).remove(); // move source after tmp, remove tmp
}
```

**EDIT**: the code above swaps 2 `td`s, which is different that what was asked (move a single `td`).

Regardless of the problem with events, if you want to move `source` before `destination`, simply do `source.insertBefore(destination)`, or `destination.before(source)`. In your code  you're moving `destination` to the end of the `tr`.

Comment: I don't manage to understand what your code is doing.. can you add comments and describe more? :)

Comment: It's actually swapping the two `td`s, by inserting a temporary `td` before the destination, moving destination after source and source after the temporary `td`. But I just realized you wanted something else - to move a column, not swap columns... working on editing my answer

Comment: I saw you changed the code - after and insertAfter. this is really confusing.. :)